# Get Value From Radio Button Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, radio-button

I know this question has been asked before, but I just cannot seem to get this right.  It always returns **undefined** error.

```
var currentAnswers = $('input[name="ans"]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();

$(document).ready (function () {
```

//

```
var answers = 
[["Fee","Fi","Fo"], 
["La","Dee","Da"]],
questions = 
["Fee-ing?",
"La-ing?"],
corAns = ["Fee", "La"];

var counter = 0;

var $facts = $('#main_ .facts_div'),
$question = $facts.find('.question'),
$ul = $facts.find('ul'),
$btn = $('.myBtn');


$btn.on('click', function() {
    if (counter < questions.length) {
        $question.text(questions[counter]);

        var ansstring = $.map(answers[counter], function(value) {
            return '<li><input type="radio" name="ans" value="0"/>'
            + value + '</li>'}).join('');
        $ul.html(ansstring);

        var currentAnswers = $('input[name="ans"]:checked').map(function() {
            return this.val();
        }).get();

        var correct = 0;
        if (currentAnswers[counter]==corAns[counter]) {
            correct++;
        }


    }
    else {
        $facts.text('You are done with the quiz ' + correct);
        $(this).hide();
    }
        counter++;
});
```

//
});

It's pretty long.  I just have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
 <div id="main_">
    <div class="facts_div">
        <span class="question"></span>
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
    <div id = "next_button">
    <form>
        <input id="x" type="button" class="myBtn" value="Press Me">
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I feel like the answer is something stupid.  Like an undeclared variable or something, but I just don't know.  I am confused.

Comment: can you share the target markup

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3AhcS/. Is this wrapped in a document ready call? When and how are you running the above code? Is it being run on dynamically created elements?

Comment: @Arun P Johny I don't know why this received a downvote... but yes.  I can share the entire code if necessary.

Comment: @JerryWalker might be because of that exact reason... there is no html to see what is happening

Comment: @j08691 Dynamically yes, document ready call, yes.  There is an array that iterates over `li` and I'm trying to get that array value and compare it to another array with correct answers in it.

Comment: I added the code.  The markup is pretty standard.  Most of what is being created is dynamically.  I can post that too if necessary.  I just didn't post it all because it's long and I figured maybe I wasn't writing that Jquery code right or something.  I understand there is a more elegant solution as well.  But, me being new this makes sense to me.  All except for getting that damn value...

Comment: Can you include the markup too?

Comment: Where are the checkboxes?

Comment: Radio buttons you mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning Value of Radio Button Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649064/returning-value-of-radio-button-jquery)

Comment: @JerryWalker see my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649064/returning-value-of-radio-button-jquery/